# cardinality of finite algebra in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

prove that every finite algebra (closed under finite union and complement) has $2^n$ elements.
Does there exist an algebra with countably infinite cardinality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ together with their complements.

Comment: @GArunkumar: I know; that’s why I said that $\mathscr{A}$ contains the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ **and their complements**. In symbols, $$\mathscr{A}=\{A\subseteq\Bbb N:A\text{ is finite or }\Bbb N\setminus A\text{ is finite}\}\;.$$

Comment: ok. but this algebra is countable?

Comment: @GArunkumar: Because the set of finite subsets of a countable set is countable, so the set of complements of a finite subsets is also countable, and the union of two countable sets is countable.

Comment: sorry. why it is an algebra? I am verifying that it is an algebra. I have some problem.

Comment: @GArunkumar: What part can’t you show?

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott finite union

Comment: your collection is actually power set of N. because every subset of N is either finite or its complement is finite.

Comment: @GArunkumar: But that’s extremely straightforward. There are two cases: all of the sets in the union are finite, or at least one of them is cofinite (i.e., the complement of a finite set). In the first case the union is clearly finite, and the second it’s clearly cofinite.

Comment: so your algebra is not countable.

Comment: @GArunkumar: It certainly is not the power set of $\Bbb N$: the set of even natural numbers is neither finite nor cofinite! You really need to review basic facts about countable and uncountable sets.

Comment: sorry.I said so in some thoughts.

Comment: ya. your example works fine. thanks.

Comment: @GArunkumar: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\mathcal{A}$ be your algebra and define the following equivalence relation on your space:
$$x\sim y \mbox{ iff }  \forall A\in\mathcal{A}\colon x\in A\Leftrightarrow y\in A.$$

Now try to show that the induced algebra on the quotient space under this equivalence is isomorphic to your original algebra.
Then try to show that the induced algebra is the power set of the quotient space and hence has cardinality $2^n$.

Comment: what is the meaning of isomorphic here?

Comment: Isomorphic as algebras, i.e. a bijection preserving union and complement. The bijection actually suffices for the argument though.